# How to receive data from associated table in CakePHP 3.x as object(currently receiving as an array)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to associate tables using `belongsTo`:
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongsto-associations

I have this code in my

> JobsController.php:

```
class JobsController extends AppController
{
    public $name = 'Jobs';

    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //Get Jobs info
        $getjobs = TableRegistry::get('Jobs');
        $jobs = $getjobs->find('all')->contain(['Types']);
        $this->set('jobs',$jobs);
    }
}
```

> JobsTable.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class JobsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('jobs');
        $this->belongsTo('types', [
            'foreignKey' => 'type_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);
    }

}
```

> TypesTable.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class TypesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('types');
    }

}
```

And I'm receiving needed data, but instead of receiving it as an object, as written in manual, I'm receiving it as an array, and It's not what is supposed to be.

> So now I'm accessing it like this(because its an array with name **types**):

```
<?php foreach($jobs as $job) : ?>
        <?php var_dump($job->types['color']); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

> But instead it supposed to be like this(according to docs it should be an object with name **type**):

```
<?php foreach($jobs as $job) : ?>
    <?php var_dump($job->type->color); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mind your casing, the association is defined as `types`, but you are containing it as `Types`, this will trip the result set grouping where the associated data is being hydrated.

```
$this->belongsTo('Types', /* ... */);
```

That should fix it.

I guess it's debatable whether this behavior might be considered as problematic or even a bug.

Comment: If i do so, it returns the same array, but with different name, instead of types it renames it to properties

Comment: @Tachi I kinda doubt that, I guess you are just misinterpreting the entity debug info. When dumping an entity via `debug()`, you'll receive pre-formatted data that, among others, makes hidden properties visible, for example the protected `_properties` is being shown as `properties`, which holds a map of names and values.